# Using the word "onto" correctly

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-in-context

I was wondering if it is possible to use the word **"onto"** in these contexts, or might it be better to use "to" instead?

> When applying this theory **onto** discrimination in promotion processes, it can be argued that men prefer to work with other men, and subsequently rather promote them, because they want to obtain the power within their own group instead of sharing it with the group of women.

> This finding can be generalized **onto** non-academic workplaces because promotion decisions are probably rarely only based on objective performance scores but there is usually some scope for personal preferences.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole sentences, as it may vary sometimes, depending on relative context?

Comment: Hello, yes sure, so this is the first sentence: "This finding can be generalized onto  non-academic workplaces because promotion decisions are probably rarely only based on objective performance scores but there is usually some scope for personal preferences" and the second one: "When applying this theory onto discrimination in promotion processes, it can be argued that men prefer to work with other men, and subsequently rather promote them, because they want to obtain the power within their own group instead of sharing it with the group of women. "

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!

Comment: Well very good. So these are the whole sentences you provided me. Since you are new here, I will edit these for you. Now you can go and see the revisions or the edit history by clicking the link above my name in your post (where it says "edited 1 min ago" or whatever minutes/hours ago). This way even you can edit the post henceforth in your upcoming questions. And always remember to provide the whole sentences beforehand. If you aren't able to find how to edit, then leave the comments or sentences or any addition in the comment section, some editor or moderator will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both those examples "to" would be better. "Onto" is used when the meaning is, at least metaphorically, "on top of".

> This code maps digits onto letters.

> I put the plate onto the table.